# How to send a automatic reply in Gmail to a forwarded message

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-canned-response

In my company, we have an info@ email address that is forwarded to me. I reply to these emails. I want to create an automatic reply (using a template) to all the emails send to this address from my own company email.

Normally when I hit reply it automatically replies to the original sender (and not to info@), however, when I use the template it sends the automatic message back to info@.

Is there any way around this?